# How to store HTML text in sql database using Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, javafx-2

I am trying to store the text generated from Java FX **html editor** to **sql database**. But I am recieving an SQL error.

I tried to use varchar(1000), varchar(max) and text **data types**.

**Error**:

[image]

**Java FX HTML Editor**

[image]

**Text Generated from Editor**

```
<html><head></head><body contenteditable="true"><p style="text-align: left;"><font face="'Segoe UI'">Line 1</font></p><p style="text-align: left;"><font face="'Segoe UI'">Line 2</font></p></body></html>
```

**Code:**

```
public String insertDept(Department dept){
String query = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME
                + "VALUES("
                +"'"+dept.getName()+"',"
                + "'"+dept.getEmail()+"'"
                + ")";
return query;
}
```

Comment: Please show the code where you are trying to store the data.

Comment: I have updated the question, please have a look

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? You used conflicting tags

Comment: Don't ever concatenate user-supplied parameters in your SQL. Google for "SQL injection"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont't know much about MySQL, but at `<font face="'Segoe UI'">` you've got the ' delimiter which probably causes your problem. Try changing it to `\'` (if it works like that in mysql)